# Is it respectful to say "our collaboration would be successful" to a professor before admission?

Tags: phrase-choice

My possible future professor has not accepted me yet. If I just say

> 1. I believe our collaboration would be successful.

and do not say

> 2. I believe, If you accept me, our collaboration will be successful.

or do not say

> 3. I believe our possible collaboration would be successful.

Is it respectful? I think using "would" instead of "will" in the first sentence implies a possible condition in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly disrespectful about any of the three forms, assuming the professor in question doesn't have an over-sized ego, to the extent that he considers students to be so below him that them collaborating with him offers no real benefit.

That said, I much prefer the first form. It's choice of "would" rather than "will" makes sense because, as you say, whether the collaboration will happen is still an open question.

The second form achieves the same thing, but in a much clumsier fashion. I'd avoid this one.

And the third form, too, is a little clumsy. There doesn't seem to be much justification for including "our possible" since most people would tend to assume that the collaboration is still contingent.